# Laravel 6.2- Sort Data based on User Defined Numbering

Tags: php, laravel

I have a bunch of data in a table in my Database, which is shown to the user as a list. Along with all the data, there is an option with empty input field, which accepts only numbers

Example :-

**i = range between 0 to max data**

```
id        Name                  Age          Order List (user input)<input type='text' id="orderlist_i">
=========================================================
1         Name 1                 25 
2         Name 2                 30
3         Name 3                 40
4         name 4                 24
5         Name 5                 23
6         Name 6                 42

Submit Button here
```

Let's say the user inputs the *Order List* as follows :-

```
id        Name                  Age          Order List (user input)<input type='text' id="orderlist_i">
=========================================================
1         Name 1                 25               5
2         Name 2                 30               6
3         Name 3                 40               1
4         name 4                 24               2
5         Name 5                 23               4
6         Name 6                 42               3

Submit Button here
```

**i = range between 0 to max data**

On clicking Submit, a bootstrap modal should open with the exact table but in sorted in ascending order based on **Order list** (i.e 1,2,3,4,etc.).

I can just show all the data, but how do I sort it based on User defined **Order List** ?

**Here is my code (no sorting done)**

```
<button type='btn btn-primary' onclick="sortData()">Submit</button>

function sortData(){
 var noOfCandidates=6;
  
  var input=[];
  for(var i=0;i<noOfCandidates;i++){
      input[i]=$('#orderlist_'+i).val();
  }
  console.log(sortedData);
   $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
      }
    }); 
      swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure want to Submit?",
        text: "",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#e7b63a',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
        reverseButtons : true
        
      }).then((result) => {
        if(result.value){
         $.ajax({ 
              type: "POST",
              url:'{{url("gosomewhere)}}',
              data:{'sort':sort},
              success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            //return false;
                  if (response.message == "success") {
                    swal({
                      title: "Something done successfully.",
                      text:response.reason,
                      type: "success"
                    }).then(function(){
                       location.reload();
                    })
                  
                    
                  } else {
                      swal({
                          title: 'Unsuccess',
                          text: response.reason
                      })
                  }
              },
              error: function(data) {
               
              }
          })
        }
        
      });
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try using collection with [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby)

My ideea would be to try and send all the data to laravel, so the entire table with the order list included for each item in the table and afterwards ...

- build a collection using all the data from the table
- sort the collection by order list
- return the collection in front
- show it in the modal